# Reliable way to get root CA certificates on Windows

Tags: c++, ssl, boost, openssl, boost-asio

I'm using boost asio to connect to my valid certificate (signed by root CA). The code I'm using is the [ssl client example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/client.cpp) available from boost docs.

The only line I added is:

```
boost::asio::ssl::context ctx(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23_client);
ctx.set_default_verify_paths(); <------------- Add default verification paths
ctx.set_password_callback(&password_callback);    

client c(io_service, ctx, iterator);

io_service.run();
```

the problem is: when using this code with a locally installed copy of openSSH (installed from a msi installer) the paths are found correctly and my certificate validated. When I download my own copy of the openSSH repository and compile it this line no longer works and I don't have root CA certificates to validate my own one (therefore **it fails**).

Since I'd like to eventually distribute these clients on customer machines I'd like to avoid setting environment variables like `SSL_CERT_DIR` and the like. How can I find root CA certificates with boost asio reliably or alternatively configure my openSSH from source compilation to find them?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can load the root CAs from the windows CA store. It already contains the "default" trusted root CA certificates and can be managed through [certmgr](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/certmgr-msc-certificate-manager-windows). Use the following function to replace set_default_verify_paths under windows:

```
#include <boost/asio/ssl/context.hpp>
#include <wincrypt.h>

void add_windows_root_certs(boost::asio::ssl::context &ctx)
{
    HCERTSTORE hStore = CertOpenSystemStore(0, "ROOT");
    if (hStore == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    X509_STORE *store = X509_STORE_new();
    PCCERT_CONTEXT pContext = NULL;
    while ((pContext = CertEnumCertificatesInStore(hStore, pContext)) != NULL) {
        X509 *x509 = d2i_X509(NULL,
                              (const unsigned char **)&pContext->pbCertEncoded,
                              pContext->cbCertEncoded);
        if(x509 != NULL) {
            X509_STORE_add_cert(store, x509);
            X509_free(x509);
        }
    }

    CertFreeCertificateContext(pContext);
    CertCloseStore(hStore, 0);

    SSL_CTX_set_cert_store(ctx.native_handle(), store);
}
```

This will load the certificates from the windows ca store. It uses d2i_X509 to convert them to the internal OpenSSL format and adds them to an OpenSSL X509_STORE. Then SSL_CTX_set_cert_store attaches that store to the boost ssl context. You can use that to set up your ssl context:

```
namespace ssl = boost::asio::ssl;
ssl::context ctx(ssl::context::tlsv12_client);
ctx.set_options(ssl::context::default_workarounds
                            | ssl::context::no_sslv2
                            | ssl::context::no_sslv3
                            | ssl::context::tlsv12_client);

#if BOOST_OS_WINDOWS
add_windows_root_certs(ctx);
#else
ctx.set_default_verify_paths();
#endif

ctx.set_password_callback(&password_callback);

client c(io_service, ctx, iterator);

io_service.run();
```

---

Note: You will probably need to add crypt32 to your linked libraries.

Note 2: BOOST_OS_WINDOWS needs [Boost Predef](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/predef.html)

Comment: Thank you. That function should be included in asio.

Comment: thank you, I don't know what set_default_verify_paths will do and get handshake error. This work.